# iBeacon ranging and proximity is buggy

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, nsnotificationcenter, ibeacon

I'm working on a class to handle all my iBeacon testing. It's purpose is to start looking for regions, range the beacons, identify them then send notifications.  The code is below.

The problem I'm having is the app is running very slowly, I know iBeacons have latency issues, and sometimes simply stops working (won't identify a close beacon).  My code is messy I know, trying to sort the logic before I work on cleaning it.  I'm wondering if I have missed a logic flaw here (and by that I mean, I wonder which logic flaws I've introduced!).

```
#import "dcBeaconManager.h"

@implementation dcBeaconManager

@synthesize currentBeaconState;

bool testRanging = false;
int firstRegionEntered = 0;
int beaconsRangedCount = 0;

- (void)initBeaconManager {
    NSLog(@"initBeaconManager called");
    self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate = self;
    NSUUID *uuid = [[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D"];
    self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:uuid identifier:@"digiConsRegion"];
    [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
    [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];

    currentBeaconState = @"initial";
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Started looking for regions");
    [self.locationManager requestStateForRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    NSLog(@"Region discovered");
    if (firstRegionEntered == 0) {
        NSLog(@"First time in region");
        UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        notification.alertBody = @"Welcome to Digial Conversations, we are upstairs.";
        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
        firstRegionEntered = 1;
    }
    [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region {
    [self.locationManager stopRangingBeaconsInRegion:self.beaconRegion];

    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.alertBody = @"We hope you enjoyed the event, thank you for coming.";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didRangeBeacons:(NSArray *)beacons inRegion:(CLBeaconRegion *)region {
    CLBeacon *beacon = [[CLBeacon alloc] init];
    beacon = [beacons lastObject];
    NSNumber *currentBeaconMajor = beacon.major;  //it's major (group) number
    NSNumber *currentBeaconMinor = beacon.minor;  //it's minor (individual) number

    if (([currentBeaconMinor floatValue] == 59204) && ([currentBeaconMajor floatValue] == 33995) && (beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear)) {
        if (beaconsRangedCount == 0) {
            currentBeaconState = @"Mint";
            beaconsRangedCount ++;
        }
        if ([currentBeaconState isEqualToString:@"Blue"] || [currentBeaconState isEqualToString:@"Purple"]) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didLocateMint" object:nil];
        }

    } else if (([currentBeaconMinor floatValue] == 7451) && ([currentBeaconMajor floatValue] == 63627) && (beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear)) {
        if (beaconsRangedCount == 0) {
            currentBeaconState = @"Blue";
            beaconsRangedCount ++;
        }
        if ([currentBeaconState isEqualToString:@"Mint"] || [currentBeaconState isEqualToString:@"Purple"]) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didLocateBlue" object:nil];
        }

    } else if (([currentBeaconMinor floatValue] == 51657) && ([currentBeaconMajor floatValue] == 26976) && (beacon.proximity == CLProximityNear)) {
        if (beaconsRangedCount == 0) {
            currentBeaconState = @"Purple";
            beaconsRangedCount ++;
        }
        if ([currentBeaconState isEqualToString:@"Mint"] || [currentBeaconState isEqualToString:@"Blue"]) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didLocatePurple" object:nil];
        }
    } else {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"didLeaveNearRegion" object:nil];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: The beacons only transmit every so many seconds, no? Did you account for that. Its not like they are in continuous transmit mode...

Comment: I'm working on Estimote iBeacon in this days and i notice some latency and some problem to identify the exit and the entrance in beacon range for send notification.. sometimes doesn't work or works lately. I've changed my beacons Advertise Interval to 50ms but nothing is changed..

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean that didEnterRegion and didExitRegion callbacks are being delayed?

If your app is running in the foreground while you are ranging, you should get entered region notifications within a second, and exit region notifications within a few seconds.   If your app is in the background, **it can take up to 15 minutes** to get either an in region or an out of region notification.

For details on this timing, see [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2013/11/13/ibeacon-monitoring-in-the-background-and-foreground.html).

These latency issues are not beacon-specific.  They have to do with the way the CoreLocation API is implemented in iOS.

Comment: Excellent write up David, thanks for sharing that link!